# Checkbox checked isnt updating a label ASP/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Im trying to change a value of a label according to the selected value but its not changing the value at all.

What im trying to do is, if its checked then label will show as low but if unchecked then value would be ok.

**C#**

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="ddlHead" value="0" runat="server" onchange="HeadDamage(this.value);" />
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function HeadDamage(Value) {

    if (Value == 0) {
        $('#<%= lblHeadDamage.ClientID %>').text("Ok");
    }
    else if (Value == 1)
        $('#<%= lblHeadDamage.ClientID %>').text("Low");
    }
```

Comment: Do you have any errors in your console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your snippet will not work because of 2 reasons. First of all a checkbox does not have a value, it is either checked or it isn't. Second if you look at the HTML you will see that asp.net has wrapped the checkbox with a `<span>` element.

```
<span onchange="HeadDamage(this.value)"><input id="mainContentPane_ddlHead" name="ctl00$mainContentPane$ddlHead" type="checkbox"></span>
```

That element contains the `HeadDamage` and thus your `Value` will always be null since the span element does not have a value.

Try this snippet with the click bound directly to the checkbox:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="ddlHead" runat="server"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#<%= ddlHead.ClientID %>").click(function () {
            if (this.checked == true) {
                $('#<%= lblHeadDamage.ClientID %>').text("Ok");
            } else {
                $('#<%= lblHeadDamage.ClientID %>').text("Low");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="ddlHead" onclick="javascript:funCalled(this)" ClientIDMode="Static" />

function funCalled(obj) {
    if (obj.checked) {
         $('#<%= lblHeadDamage.ClientID %>').text("Ok");
    } else {
        $('#<%= lblHeadDamage.ClientID %>').text("Low");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few issues with your code.

1st. The `val` attribute of the checkbox will never change.

2nd. The `text()` function of `jQuery` will not work for a checkbox. You will need to add a label next to it.

An example will be:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="ddlHead" value="0" />
<label id="lblHead">low</label>

// when DOM loads
$(document).ready(function() {

  // when the checkbox changes, run the following function
  $(document).on('change', '#ddlHead', function() {

    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      // if this is checked
      $('#lblHead').text('ok');
    } else {
      // else, low
      $('#lblHead').text('low');
    }
  });
});
```

working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4rcs0msz/1/